# Can't connect to SSH on a Raspberry PI

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I am getting an error logging into a raspberry pi over ssh. I am using the `pi` user and I am getting a connection reset from the host.

Verbose output from the ssh client below:

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 172.16.0.2:22 as 'pi'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen ~/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 172.16.0.2 port 22
```

I have tried googling `SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent` and `Connection reset by 172.16.0.2 port 22` and I have not found anything. I have repeatedly restarted the `PI` and restarted the ssh server however I am not making any progress on this one.

Where would I start looking to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Try enabling an older Host Key algorithm, `ssh -o 'HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa' pi@172.16.0.2:22`